# MySQL query increase relevance by amount of matching fields

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find a way to relate certain items in my database based on their stats, however I been trying to get this to work with different queries without any succes.

So a user can select an item and search for similar items. Items have different stats ( primary, secondary, ... ). I want to present the search result depending on relevance ( the amount of fields that match with primary being the most important etc )

My database has 5 fields:

ID/name/primary/secondary/tertiary

I tried the "match against" method but so far without succes.

---

edit:

example: matching dokters by their studyfield

1. dokter1 > psychology ( primary ) > dimentia
2. dokter2 > psychology > dimentia
3. dokter3 > psychology > adhd
4. dokter4 > oncology > breastcancer

now the goal is to search matches that are similar to dr1. dokter 1-2 are a perfect match, 3 is slightly off but still a better match then dokter 4 who has nothing in common.

Comment: You'll need to at least show some sample data and expected output.

Comment: updated my post, i hope its clearer now.

Comment: You could add points to a calculated column based on it's matches with IF. ex: SELECT *,`IF(name = 'myname', 1, 0) + IF(primary = 'myprimary', 1, 0) AS Score` FROM someTable

Comment: thank you that seemed to have worked